# Why is this module cyclic?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I've read that given a representation of a Lie algebra $(\rho, V)$ and its extension to $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$, namely $(\tilde{\mathfrak{\rho}}, V)$, if we fix $v \in V$, we can define the ideal $$I = \{x \in \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}): x\cdot v = 0  \}$$ Then the quotient  $ \ \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})/I$ is cyclic (generated by one element) as a $\mathfrak{g}$-module. But I can't see why this is the case, can someone explain it to me?

Comment: If $R$ is a unital associative ring and $I$ a left ideal then $R/I$ is a left $R$-module cyclically generated by $1+I$, no?

Comment: @runway44 but if it is cyclic $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module, does it mean it is cyclic $\mathfrak{g}$-module?

Comment: @runway44 I understand why it's a cyclic $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$-module, but I don't see why it's a cyclic $\mathfrak{g}$-module.

Comment: A $\mathfrak{g}$-module is the same thing as a $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a unital associative ring and $I$ a left ideal, then the quotient $R/I$ is a left $R$-module. It is straightforward to verify $R/I$ is cyclically generated by $1+I$ as an $R$-module.

We can apply this to $R=\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ and your annihilator ideal $I=\mathrm{Ann}_{\,\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})}(x)$. Note that $V$, as a representation of $\mathcal{g}$, automatically becomes a $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$-module by simply extending the action.

For a $\mathfrak{g}$-module $M$, the cyclic submodule generated by some $m\in M$ is the smallest submodule containing $m$. In practice, that means it is spanned by $m$, and $\rho(X)m$ for all $X\in\mathfrak{g}$, and $\rho(X)\rho(Y)m$ for all $X,Y$, and so on - in other words, the cyclic $\mathfrak{g}$-submodule generated by $m$ is the same as the cyclic $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$-module generated by $m$ as well.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. But it seems in the last paragraph, you are showing that if $M$ is a cyclic $\mathfrak{g}$-module then $M$ is a cyclic $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module, which I agree. But what we need is that if $M$ is a cyclic $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module, then $M$ is a cyclic $\mathfrak{g}$-module. I think these two are different statements?

Comment: @Tengu The cyclic $\frak{g}$-submodule generated by $m$ and the $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$-submodule generated by $m$ are the same thing. That is the last sentence in my answer. Therefore, if $m$ cyclically generates $M$ as a ${\cal U}({\frak g})$-module, it must also generate $M$ as a $\frak g$-module, no?

Comment: Ah I see it now, Thanks! $\rho(X)\rho(Y)m$ is still in $\rho(\mathfrak{g})m$ so it is equal to some $\rho(Z)m$ where $Z\in \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @Tengu Actually that's not true, $\rho(X)\rho(Y)m$ may not be expressible as $\rho(Z)m$. Indeed $\rho({\frak g})m$ by itself may not actually be a $\frak g$-module, since it may not be closed under multiplication by $\rho(X)$s. The cyclic submodule generated by $\frak g$ has to be closed under multiplication, though, so if it contains $m$ it must contain $\rho(X)m$s, and it it contains $\rho(X)m$s it must also contain $\rho(Y)\rho(X)m$s, and so on.